# Problema al concatenar valores en una clase

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta que genera una tabla horizontal

```
SELECT a.cod, a.nom,
SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = 202201 THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = 202202 THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END)
FROM cliente a, 
     ctacte b
WHERE a.cod_ = b.caux 
AND   b.periodo >= 202201
AND   b.periodo <= 202202
GROUP BY b.caux
ORDER BY b.caux;
```

Pero ahora quiero que esto mismo se haga a través de una clase pasando como parametro el año.

```
public function saldos($anio) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT a.cod, a.nom,
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = CONCAT(:anio1, '01') THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END),
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = CONCAT(:anio2, '02') THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END)
                FROM cliente a, 
                     ctacte b
                WHERE a.cod = b.caux 
                AND   b.periodo >= CONCAT(:anio1, '01')
                AND   b.periodo <= CONCAT(:anio2, '02')
                GROUP BY b.caux
                ORDER BY b.caux";
        $bd = new ConexionDB();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio2', $anio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

El parámetro es el año y los meses (01, 02, etc. serían fijos) por eso uso CONTAT().
Pero no genera nada. El error que muestra el catch es:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

Pero solamente se para un solo parámetro el año a través de `$anio`.

Actualicé. Quité los apostrofes de `:anio1` y `:anio2` en los `CONCAT()` del `Select` y del `Where`.

**ACTUALIZACION:**

```
public function saldos($anio) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT a.cod, a.nom,
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = CONCAT(:anio1, '01') THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END),
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = CONCAT(:anio2, '02') THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END)
                FROM cliente a, 
                     ctacte b
                WHERE a.cod = b.caux 
                AND   b.periodo >= :anio1
                AND   b.periodo <= :anio2
                GROUP BY b.caux
                ORDER BY b.caux";
        $bd = new ConexionDB();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio."01", PDO::PARAM_INT);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio2', $anio."02", PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Lo hice con comillas y con apóstrofes. Con este cambio muestra el error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\###programa.php:162 Stack trace: #0
```

Que es en la línea de `$stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio."01", PDO::PARAM_INT);`

También dejé los `CONCAT()` del `select` y puse los periodos para probar:

```
AND   b.periodo >= 202201
AND   b.periodo <= 202202
```

Así que el problema está en el `bindparam` o en el `where`.

Comment: Fíjate en las dobles comillas que usas dentro de la consulta. Hasta en el código que has puesto en la pregunta se ven raras (me refiero a los AS).  Mira que no sea eso.

Comment: El select funciona así como está. Y en la clase le quité los AS "01"  que mencionas y nada.

Comment: No tenias que quitarlos, sino escapar las comillas dobles o bien ponerles comillas simples, así:  `AS '01'`.

Comment: Otra cosa que no tengo tan clara es si realmente hacen falta las comillas simples cada vez que usas una variable con los dos puntos: `':anio1'`  pues creo que debería ser sin ellas:  `:anio1`

Comment: Sobre los AS ese no es el problema, incluso le puse comillas simples y nada. Las quité y nada. Y sobre los dos puntos en `:anio1` así se utiliza en bindparam [ver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: No digo en bindParam, sino en la consulta en si: `CONCAT(':anio1', '01')`  (perdón, parece que quiera confundirte, me debo estar expresando fatal, je)

Comment: También las quité de allí y nada.

Comment: Pues diria que a esas variables del **bindParam** no les gusta que las traten como **string** dentro de un `CONCAT`... ¿y si lo pruebas así?  `$stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio."01", PDO::PARAM_INT);` y quitas todos los `CONCAT(:anio1, '01')` y los sustituyes por `:anio1`?  (y lo mismo con el otro, claro)

Comment: Muestra esto `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in codigo`

Comment: ¿eso en que línea? ¿puedes actualizar la pregunta con esos cambios a ver como ha quedado?

Comment: vale, última prueba, y aquí lo dejo... según leo por ahí, no se puede usar el mismo placeholder (bindParam) dos o más veces en una sentencia, por lo tanto prueba hacer 4 bindParam con distintos nombres como `:anio1`, `:anio2`, `anio3`, y `:anio4` con los valores que quieras, aunque esten repetidos, y cambias la consulta acorde con eso.  Si esto ya no tira abandono :-)

Comment: En cuanto al problema de esta línea: `$stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio."01", PDO::PARAM_INT);` seguramente es que no le gusta que hagamos esa concatenación dentro del bindParam, y podrías probar con estas dos líneas en su lugar: `$anio1 = $anio."01";` y luego `$stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio1, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: No entendí lo de los `4 bindParam`. Si te das cuenta yo estoy usando dos `:anio1` y `:anio2` que son alimentados por el $anio que entra a la clase. Y lo hice así precisamente porque sé que no se puede repetir. Salvo que yo haya entenido mal.

Comment: Te lo pongo en una respuesta de forma completa, para que me entiendas

Comment: vale, prueba esa respuesta a ver si cuela esta vez o te da algun nuevo error

Comment: he hecho un nuevo cambio en la respuesta para eliminar un par de variables que no hacen falta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pruébalo así, pues según parece no se puede usar el mismo *placeholder* (`bindParam`) dos o más veces en una sentencia, por lo tanto prueba hacer **4** `bindParam` con distintos nombres como `:anio1`, `:anio2`, `anio3`, y `:anio4` con los valores que quieras, *aunque esten repetidos*, y cambias la consulta acorde con eso:

```
public function saldos($anio) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT a.cod, a.nom,
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = :anio1 THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END) AS '01',
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.periodo = :anio2 THEN b.importe_s ELSE 0 END) AS '02'
                FROM cliente a, 
                     ctacte b
                WHERE a.cod = b.caux 
                AND   b.periodo >= :anio3
                AND   b.periodo <= :anio4
                GROUP BY b.caux
                ORDER BY b.caux";
        $bd = new ConexionDB();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $anio1 = $anio."01";
        $anio2 = $anio."02";
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio1', $anio1, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio2', $anio2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio3', $anio1, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':anio4', $anio2, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Claro era obvio, no lo vi y allí estaba.